# How to track video with Google Analytics

Tags: php, google-analytics

I have been suffering with this for weeks now but my analytics data still doesn't show that the video was started at least 1 time.

This is a video in an iframe:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/ILawZYq4UPA" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

It will actually be opened in a popup

```
<a class="youtube" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ILawZYq4UPA"></a>
```

This is done with the help of http://lab.abhinayrathore.com/jquery_youtube/

I have this code block I am playing with to track the video:

```
<script>

    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag); 

    var player;
    var lastAction = '';
        function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
            player = new YT.Player('player', {
                height: '600',
                width: '800',
                videoId: 'ILawZYq4UPA',
                events: {
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
            });
        }

        function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
            switch (event.data){
                case YT.PlayerState.PLAYING:
                    ga('send', 'event', 'video', 'Playing', 'ILawZYq4UPA');
                    break;
                case YT.PlayerState.ENDED:
                    ga('send', 'event', 'video', 'Completed', 'ILawZYq4UPA');
                    break;
                case YT.PlayerState.PAUSED:
                    if (lastAction != 'paused'){
                    ga('send', 'event', 'video', 'Paused', 'ILawZYq4UPA');
                    }else{
                        lastAction = 'paused';
                    }
                    break;
                }
          }
            
    
    </script>
```

I set up a goal in GA to track the number of plays:

[image]

I am using Universal Analytics. I can track button clicks, funnels and so on. Am I missing something?

Comment: Any ideas? Someone must have a hint at least

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that looks different from your code and the one I'm using (and works) is that yours doesn't have `onPlayerReady`:

`events: {
  'onReady': onPlayerReady,
  'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
 }`